# Show/Hide content with Jquery, MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC to show on my page comments on a given post. This is my code:

```
@foreach (var comment in post.Comments)
{
    <div>
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Post", new { userId = comment.UserId })" height="50" width="50"/>
        @Html.DisplayFor(c => comment.User.FirstName)
        @Html.DisplayFor(c => comment.User.LastName):
        @Html.DisplayFor(c => comment.Text)
        @Html.DisplayFor(c => comment.DateComment)
    </div>
    <hr />
}
```

So it gives all the comments for the given post. How can I show the latest 3 post, and the rest can be loaded with a "More" button using jquery?

Comment: I would suggest no loading any comments initially. On page load do an ajax request to a different page that builds the comments for you with a `GET` parameter for `start` that will return the comments for more by just adding to the start parameter.

Comment: hm... i think it would be easier if i use some script to show part of the comments

Comment: Try returning only latest 3 comments from controller action.Add link for "more..",when click make ajax call to return comments from latest 4th to specified size say(10/20).

Answer (score 0):

order the comments by latest ones first, then on each show more

```
// if you have a comments class on each comment div
$('div.comments').not(':visible')[0].show();
$('div.comments').not(':visible')[1].show();
$('div.comments').not(':visible')[2].show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this but it is not a good approach because you have already fetched all the results.

```
@{
       var LatestComments = post.Comments..OrderByDescending( c => c.DateComment ).ToList();
 }    


@for(int i = 0 ; i<3 ; ++i)
{
    <div>
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Post", new { userId = comment.UserId })" height="50" width="50"/>
        @Html.DisplayFor(c => LatestComments[i].User.FirstName)
        @Html.DisplayFor(c => LatestComments[i].User.LastName):
        @Html.DisplayFor(c => LatestComments[i].Text)
        @Html.DisplayFor(c => LatestComments[i].DateComment)
    </div>
    <hr />
}
```

A more better approach will be to fetch only few records in your DAL and then send to the View. Later you can make Ajax calls for more comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
        //get collapse content selector
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');                   

        //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
          if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
                            //change the button label to be 'Show'
            toggle_switch.html('Show');
          }else{
                            //change the button label to be 'Hide'
            toggle_switch.html('Hide');
          }
        });
      });

    }); 
    </script>
    <style> 
    .round-border {
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    </style>
```

### jQuery toggle() to hide/show collapse content

Show

Bla bla bla bla

pls try this